# Recovery of form field values upon calling of same file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file which displays the resultset of a query. Now there is an option to compare the individual records (maximum upto 4 simultaneously). Problem is when I switch to next page, the previously selected values for comparison are lost (as the same file loads new records afresh, through pagination algorithm). Is there anyway, I could pass the selected values from the first selection and thereon to the final call(of same page). Technology being used is PHP, MySQL & Javascript. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark without some sample code or a clear explanation of the pagination, but if you are using a form then you can pass the selections to hidden fields, session variables or some other scoped variable.  It appears you are using AJAX, but without the code, I can't give you specifics.  If you have full access to the code then a click function on the selection of the elements would allow you to pass the variables via AJAX store them via JAVASCRIPT.

If you can provide a few more details, my answer can be more specific.  I would have just asked for clarification but I just joined and don't have the 'reputation' for that yet. ;-)